# incremental average using excel

Tags: excel, moving-average, visual-studio-macros, vba

I need to take the average of every 2 point increment, my data is in columns "a", as an example , and the average in column "b"

```html
a1 b1=0
a2 b2=a1
a3 b3=average(a1,a2)
a4 b4=average(a2,a3)
a5 b5=average(a3,a4)
...
```

I need an excel  formula or macro to do so , any ideas?

Comment: Your equation is already correct.  Enter `=AVERAGE(A1,A2)` into cell B3 and drag it too the bottom of your range (or double click the drag handle in the bottom right corner of cell B3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do it once and not write a macro for it, try this: 
Enter in CELL B3: `=(a1+a2)/2` en drag this down to the end of your rows.